# Jupyter notebook does not show print output Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I use jupyter notebook with the following configuration:

Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)
IPython 7.19.0
serveur version : 6.1.4

I use it to do data science with python 3.8.1
However, none of my prints are displayed ....

Could you help me to solve this problem?

I try to restart the kernel but nothing append

some screen shot

1. library

[image]

[image]

2. after I just do some function

[image]

3. and I us it

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some screenshots? So that people can see that's actually there

Comment: I will edit and post some screen shots but I don't think the problem is with my code because a simple print("Hello World") does not work. thank you